# why can't I render the Column myself in a "helper" component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, fixed-data-table

I have the following SSCCE in React using [fixed-data-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixed-data-table):

```
const rows = [{name: 'Apple', desc: 'a popular fruit'},
              {name: 'Cat',   desc: 'a domesticated feline'}];


const App = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <Table id='foo'
            height={200}
            width={400}
            rowsCount={rows.length}
            rowHeight={26}
            headerHeight={50}>
                <Column
                    width={0}
                    flexGrow={2}
                    cell={props=>(<Cell>{rows[props.rowIndex].name}</Cell>)}
                    header='Name'/>
                <Column
                    width={0}
                    flexGrow={2}
                    cell={props=>(<Cell>{rows[props.rowIndex].desc}</Cell>)}
                    header='Description'/>
            </Table>
        );
    }
});
```

The above works and renders both columns:

[image]

Now I am trying to create my own helper component to simplify the `Column` interface:

```
const EnhancedColumn = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log('render called');
        return (
                    <Column
                    width={0}
                    flexGrow={2}
                    cell={props=>(<Cell>{rows[props.rowIndex].name}</Cell>)}
                    header='Name'/>
        );
    }
});

const App2 = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <Table id='foo'
            height={200}
            width={400}
            rowsCount={rows.length}
            rowHeight={26}
            headerHeight={50}>
                <EnhancedColumn/>
                <Column
                    width={0}
                    flexGrow={2}
                    cell={props=>(<Cell>{rows[props.rowIndex].desc}</Cell>)}
                    header='Description'/>
            </Table>
        );
    }
});
```

Suddenly the `EnhancedColumn` is not rendered at all (in fact its render method is not even called as the message `render is called` does not appear on the console):

[image]

I logged this as an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/issues/413).

Comment: One thing I noticed is you aren't passing props down to populate the enhanced column's data. 

Also it's kinda hard to debug this without the root usage of those components, so you should add a little bit more code for context!

Comment: @Dibesjr there's no `props` to pass. Root usage is trivial: `ReactDOM.render(<App/> , $('#app')[0]);` (or `App2/` when it clips the first column).

Comment: Where is the data coming from? 

EDIT: Nevermind saw where you store your mock data

Comment: Are your rendering all of your children in the table component?